# MongoDB - Structuring and querying models and schema for many to many relationships

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

Trying to battle the shortcomings of relationships in MongoDB, here is what I am trying to have in my database:

**Models:**

1. Users: (already have many users in the database) mostly queried via their `uid` but the `_id` is also available.
2. Teams: Contains 1 owner, multiple members, projects and assets.
3. Members: Can belong to multiple teams, each member can have different roles. A member can belong to multiple teams with different roles.
4. Roles: Belongs to members. A member can have a different role in each team they belong to. ['view', 'edit', 'admin']. **Roles can also be embedded in the Members model to go with the hybrid method.**
5. Projects: projects can be independent or part of a team, the access to the projects which belong to teams is determined by the member's role.
6. Assets: Assets can be independent or part of a team, the access to the assets which belong to teams is determined by the member's role. An asset can contain multiple projects too.

**Specifications:**

Each user can be a member of a team or independent users of the application. Normal users can have their own private projects and assets.

A member of a team can have access to assets and projects that the team owner decided they can have access to.

A member can create their own private assets and projects.

Depending on the member's role, a member can also share assets with their team members.

A member, depending on their roles can add, remove, edit assets of a team, delete or rename a team, add or remove members from the team.

A member can view the list of the assets and projects shared with them within the team.

A member can view single assets page, where they can add remove items in the asset, depending on their roles.

A member can view, edit, add, remove single projects, depending on their roles.

**Current Schema:**

```
const teamSchema = new Schema({
  uid: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  members: {
    type: [String]
  },
  brands: {
    type: [String]
  }
}, { collection: 'team', timestamps: true });

const memberSchema = new Schema({
  uid: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  owner: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  teamID: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
  },
  acl: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ['view', 'copy', 'edit', 'admin', 'owner'],
    default: 'view'
  },
  pending: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  }
}, { collection: 'member', timestamps: true, _id: false });

const assetsSchema = new Schema({
  uid: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  fonts: [AssetFile],
  colors: [Color],
  logos: [AssetFile],
  images: [AssetFile],
  projects: Array,
  items: Array,
  members: [String]
}, { collection: 'branding', timestamps: true });

const userSchema = new Schema({
  uid: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true,
    index: { unique: true },
    validate: v => validator.isEmail(v)
  },
  avatar: String,
  files: [FilesSchema],
  isAdmin: Boolean,
  projectCount: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  userName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  userType: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: 'Free User'
  },
  lastSeenAt: {
    type: Date
  },
}, { collection: 'user', timestamps: true });

const projectSchema = new Schema({
  uid: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  objects: Array,
  projectTitle: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: 'Untitled Project'
  },
  preview: {
    type: String
  },
  folder: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: null
  },
  archived: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
}, { collection: 'project', timestamps: true });
```

---

These can be easily achieved in relational databases, but since my app is already out in the open with more than 40K users, moving to another DB is not an easy option.

Could these be achieved in MongoDB and how, or should I stop trying and move to another DB?

I am already using mongoose, but I am also open to using native MongoDB codes (such as aggregate, $lookup etc.)

**EDIT:**

It is more the question of scalability for me than learning how to write queries in MongoDB, so here are the queries I already have:

**List of Assets:**

```
const personalAssets = await AssetsModel.aggregate([
    { $match: { uid: user.uid } },
    { $project: { _id: 1, uid: 1, title: 1, logos: 1, teamID: 1, acl: 'owner', createdAt: 1, fonts: 1 } },
    { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } }
]);

const sharedAssets = await MemberModel.aggregate([
    {
    $match: {
        $or: [
        { uid: user.uid },
        { owner: user._id }
        ]
    }
    },
    { $project: { _id: 0, acl: 1, teamID: 1, owner: 1 } },
    {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'team',
        let: { team_id: '$teamID' },
        pipeline: [
        {
            $match: {
            $expr: {
                $eq: [ '$_id', '$$team_id' ]
            }
            }
        },
        { $project: { _id: 0, assets: 1, teamID: '$$team_id' } }
        ],
        as: 'team'
    }
    },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ '$team', 0 ] }, '$$ROOT' ] } } },
    { $project: { assets: 1, acl: 1, teamID: 1, owner: 1 } },
    { $match: { 'assets.0': { $exists: true } } },
    {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'branding',
        let: { 'assets': '$assets' },
        pipeline: [
        {
            $match: {
            $expr: {
                $and: [
                { $in: [ '$_id', '$$assets' ] },
                { $ne: [ '$uid', user.uid ] }
                ]
            }
            }
        }
        ],
        as: 'assets'
    }
    },
    { $unwind: '$assets' },
    {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: ['$assets', { acl: '$acl' }, { teamID: '$teamID' }, { owner: '$owner' }]
        }
    }
    },
    {
    $project: {
        assets: 1,
        acl: {
        $cond: {
            if: { $eq: [ user._id, '$owner' ] },
            then: 'owner',
            else: '$acl'
        }
        },
        _id: 1,
        uid: 1,
        title: 1,
        teamID: 1,
        logos: 1,
        fonts: 1
    }
    }
]);

return [...personalAssets, ...sharedAssets];
```

**Single assets:**

```
const personalAsset = await AssetsModel.findOne({ _id, uid: user.uid });
if (brand) asset.acl = 'owner';

const sharedAsset = await MemberModel.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
        $and: [
            { teamID: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(teamID) },
            {
            $or: [
                { uid: user.uid },
                { owner: user._id }
            ]
            }
        ]
        }
    },
    { $project: { _id: 0, acl: 1, teamID: 1, owner: 1 } },
    {
        $lookup: {
        from: 'team',
        pipeline: [
            {
            $match: {
                $expr: {
                $and: [
                    { $eq: [ '$_id', mongoose.Types.ObjectId(teamID) ] },
                    { $in: [ mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id), '$assets' ] }
                ]
                }
            }
            },
            { $project: { _id: 0, assets: 1, teamID: teamID } }
        ],
        as: 'team'
        }
    },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ '$team', 0 ] }, '$$ROOT' ] } } },
    { $match: { 'assets.0': { $exists: true } } },
    {
        $lookup: {
        from: 'branding',
        pipeline: [
            {
            $match: {
                $expr: {
                $eq: [ '$_id', mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id) ]
                }
            }
            }
        ],
        as: 'assets'
        }
    },
    { $unwind: '$assets' },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: {
            $mergeObjects: [
            '$assets',
            {
                acl: {
                $cond: {
                    if: { $eq: [ user._id, '$owner' ] },
                    then: 'owner',
                    else: '$acl'
                }
                }
            },
            { teamID: '$teamID' }
            ]
        }
        }
    }
]);

brand = sharedAsset[0];
```

Same goes for folders and projects as well. The main challenge here is when getting the list of assets and getting the member ACL (access control level). It is easier to do this for single assets (folders and projects).

My main question is how to structure my schema and the query them in a more scalable way.

Comment: I have used $lookup to combine multiple collections. If you are opting for a nosql database like mongo, your current schema imo is not the best one. Firstly it is a little difficult to express your queries using aggregate.Secondly, it is not the easiest to maintain as your requirements grow. My advice would be to migrate to a rdbms before it gets too let or denormalize your current schema. Mongo was never meant to do what your trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's not yet published, so I do have the option to re-write the schema for all of the above except for the user schema. How do you suggest to denormalize the schema and then query/aggregate according to what I explained above?

Comment: Would you be able to share what is the actual problem you're having. Any particular query/aggregation that you couldn't achieve? If it's performance, what's the bottleneck ? etc.

Comment: @WanBachtiar I just edited my question and added the query I am using for the assets schema. I have all the queries working for me, my main worry is its scalability in the future. For example, in the coming months, there will be real-time collaboration added, and I want my data to be structured in a way that makes it easier to expand.

Comment: Though aggregations should work well with indexed keys in $match you can also consider running multiple read queries in parallel and combining them in your application. (If you have reference based relationships in the root model). Mongo retrieval times are very fast on indexed keys. Nodejs makes async parallel execution second nature for you (it was designed for this type of stuff). The response time will not be as slow as you might be expecting out of habit. Side note: your schema can be simplified for a more NoSQL suited modelling.

Comment: @Shasak I am already using the parallel async requests which work great when I am fetching single documents. The tricky part is fetching arrays and then matching the acl with the asset or member results. The aggregated queries do the job. I just hope they are scalable too. For your side note, how do you suggest denormalizing it to be simplified and more NoSQL suited modeling?